# Get Port Number & Host Name in a Spring Application on Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My application is an `Spring framework 3.1.2` based Web-application deployed on `Apache tomcat 6`.

I need to get my running application **port-number** and **host-name** on application(server) Start-up. So that I would override it on a property and it is need for Other bean initialization.

Does the spring provides any options to retrieves these details and to set it on Server Startup?..

Answer (score 6):

Take a look into those two questions previously asked: [Get the server port number from tomcat with out a request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867197/get-the-server-port-number-from-tomcat-with-out-a-request) and [I need to know the HTTP and HTTPS port my java webapp is running on webapp startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481432/i-need-to-know-the-http-and-https-port-my-java-webapp-is-running-on-webapp-start). There you will see how to get port from a Connector, connector also has getDomain method that would give you host name.

Since you know how to get without spring, you can have a bean that gets those details and provides them for the other bean that needs those instantiation detail. There are few ways to do that:

1) Create Spring factory bean that would get port, hostname and instantiates bean you want

2) Have separate bean that holds those details for you and you use that bean to construct other one

3) You override your application details with port and domain and when instantiating bean that needs them have a init method that would read them for your new bean

Answer (score 5):

Here is code for getting port an dip address

```
class IPAddressDemo{
    public static String getIpAddressAndPort1() throws MalformedObjectNameException, NullPointerException,
            UnknownHostException {
        MBeanServer beanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        Set<ObjectName> objectNames = beanServer.queryNames(new ObjectName("*:type=Connector,*"),
                Query.match(Query.attr("protocol"), Query.value("HTTP/1.1")));
        String host = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        String port = objectNames.iterator().next().getKeyProperty("port");
        String ipadd = "http" + "://" + host + ":" + port;
        System.out.println(ipadd);
        return ipadd;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's ideas solution if Proxy is replacing real Connector's port number (configured in server.xml) and you need to get it. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score -3):

Tomcat will run by default on TCP/IP port number `8080`.

Steps

1. Navigate to `C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.18\conf\server.xml` (The place where you have installed tomcat)
2. In server.xml file, find **Connector port** looking like the following

   ```
   <connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectiontimeout="20000" redirectport="8443">     

   </connector>
   ```

port in the Connector tag is your port no.

Finding hostnames:

Steps

```
1. Navigate to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc`
```

Or

> start->All Programs->Run-> type 'drivers'  (Without quotes)->etc

1. Open the file host with a text editor and you can find

> ```
> 127.0.0.1       localhost
> ```

From this you can understand what your hostname is.

Thanks.

Comment: I want these details(portNumber & HostName) at run-time (i.e Programmatically). Not at manual check!.

Answer (score -4):

The ServletRequest object that has been passed to your doGet, or doPost method has `getServerName()` and `getServerPort()` methods that provide this information.

Example:

```
public void doGet(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {
    System.out.println("Host Name = " + request.getServerName());
    System.out.println("Port Number = " + request.getServerPort());
}
```

Comment: dude, have you even read the question? this answer is as bad as your first one... totally worth a downvote.

Comment: The question is about Spring MVC, not servlets.